# The Time value is not reflecting correctly in my excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I managed to create an Excel file and tried to update the current system timings into first cell of the worksheet. But when the file is created, I get wrong values for timings. I want the current system time but it is displaying 12:00:00  However date is being displayed correctly.

I am using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. I need help to get the current system timings or need to reflect the timings as per the date time picker.
Here is my code:

```
namespace Test6attendance
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Excel.Application xlApp;
           Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
           Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
           object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
           xlApp = new Excel.Application();
           xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
           xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
           xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");                        

           xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue,      misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
           xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
           xlApp.Quit();
           releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
           releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
           releaseObject(xlApp);                                 
           MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
       }

       private void releaseObject(object obj)
       {       
           try
           {
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
               obj = null;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               obj = null;
               MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
           }
           finally
           {
               GC.Collect();
           }
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the following line:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
```

DateTime.Now.Date will set the time property to Midnight. Use this Instead

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Here is the [DateTime.Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please select my answer as The answer as it resolves your problem.

Comment: I am sorry I dont know that before. Just now noticed the tick mark :)